# Python program with strange algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers, output, binary-tree

I don't know really how to explain it, but I need to write a Python program that should output this:

```
1
2
1-2
3
4
3-4
1-2-3-4
5
6
5-6
7
8
7-8
5-6-7-8
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
```

Can someone help me and explain me how to do that?

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: Maybe you can consider the following problem. Given a string S of length L, you have to output a string F(S), where F(S) = S if L = 1, and F(S) = F(S1) + F(S2) + S if L > 1 with S1 the first half of S and S2 the second half of S. How do you compute the function F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok one solution would be the following:

```
lst = list(range(1,9))

def func(l):
    lst_str = list(map(str, lst))
    for i in l:
        print(i)
        for dvd in (2, 4, 8):
            if i % dvd == 0:
                print("-".join(lst_str[i-dvd:i]))
        
func(lst)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
1-2
3
4
3-4
1-2-3-4
5
6
5-6
7
8
7-8
5-6-7-8
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
```

this would fail for other series, so maybe instead of the *element itself* in the sequence we want to check *its position* in the list.
For example:

```
lst = list(range(9,17))

def func(l):
    lst_str = list(map(str, lst))
    for n, i in enumerate(l):
        print(i)
        n += 1
        for dvd in (2, 4, 8):
            if n % dvd == 0:
                print("-".join(lst_str[n-dvd:n]))
        
func(lst)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
9
10
9-10
11 
12
11-12
9-10-11-12
13
14
13-14
15
16
15-16
13-14-15-16
9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16
```

You can extend this to more power of two, so instead of iterating just for `(2, 4, 8)` you could use `[2**n for n in range(1,max_exp + 1)]` where `max_exp` is an input of your choice

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this program needs to run like this:

```
output first number
output second number
output first-second numbers
output third number
output fourth number
output third-fourth numbers
output first to fourth numbers
(same for five to eight)
output all eight
```

Have a think about the pattern here, and see if you can solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the problem has already been solved and an answer has been selected, but a more generic algorithm came to mind, which I feel compelled to share. We repeatedly concatenate previous patterns (delimited by "-"), and this concatenation happens 1x for each perfect power of 2 that our iteration number is divisible by. Therefore, with some bit checking and stack manipulation, we can very easily abstract the problem away into a solution that will work with any size input, any character set, etc., and will even behave well on non-power-of-two sized inputs.

```
def print_patterns(alphabet, delimiter="-"):
    stack = []

    def push(pattern):
        print(pattern)
        stack.append(pattern)

    def pop():
        pat1 = stack.pop()
        pat2 = stack.pop()
        return f"{pat2}{delimiter}{pat1}"

    for index, char in enumerate(alphabet, 1):
        push(char)

        for bit in reversed(bin(index)):
            if bit != '0':
                break
            push(pop())
```

Example output:

```
>>> print_patterns("12345678")
1
2
1-2
3
4
3-4
1-2-3-4
5
6
5-6
7
8
7-8
5-6-7-8
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
```

And an edge case:

```
>>> print_patterns("abcdef", "*")
a
b
a*b
c
d
c*d
a*b*c*d
e
f
e*f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of [@fanfly's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270560/python-program-with-strange-algorithm/70273415#comment124219661_70270560), using a recursive generator:

```py
def f(s):
    if len(s) >= 2:
        m = (len(s)+1)//2
        yield from f(s[:m])
        yield from f(s[m:])
    yield '-'.join(iter(s))
```

Testing:

```py
>>> print('\n'.join(   f('abcd')   ))
a
b
a-b
c
d
c-d
a-b-c-d

>>> print('\n'.join(   f(''.join(map(str, range(1,9))))  ))
1
2
1-2
3
4
3-4
1-2-3-4
5
6
5-6
7
8
7-8
5-6-7-8
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8
```